# How to filter ng-repeat with 'if statement'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of properties. I need to be able to filter them by number of rooms chosen from .

I have the options: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5+

It works all the way, except for displaying properties with more than 5 rooms.

This is my filter

```
<select class="form-control w-100" ng-model="searchRooms.rooms">
    <option value="">Alle</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5+</option>
</select>
```

And this is my ng-repeat

```
<div class="boliger" ng-repeat="bolig in boliger | filter: searchCity">
        <a href="index.php?page=single&id={{bolig.id}}" target="_blank">
            <div class="bolig-image">
                <img src="uploads/{{bolig.image}}" alt="{{bolig.type}}">
            </div>
            <div class="bolig-text-wrapper">
                <div class="bolig-titel">
                    {{bolig.titel}}
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">
                  {{bolig.rooms}} værelser - {{bolig.areal}} m² - {{bolig.by}}
                    <div class="float-right">
                      Oprettet: {{bolig.oprettelsesdato}}
                    </div>
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="bolig-husleje">
                {{bolig.husleje}},-
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Is there some kind of way to make an if-statement, that says if searchRooms.rooms is equal 5, it will not only display properties with 5 rooms, but also more?

Comment: Write a custom filter for this. Using `ng-if` won't be nearly as performant

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :)

```
<div class="boliger" ng-repeat="bolig in boliger | filter: searchCity | filter: roomsFilter">
    <a href="index.php?page=single&id={{bolig.id}}" target="_blank">
        <div class="bolig-image">
            <img src="uploads/{{bolig.image}}" alt="{{bolig.type}}">
        </div>
        <div class="bolig-text-wrapper">
            <div class="bolig-titel">
                {{bolig.titel}}
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">
              {{bolig.rooms}} værelser - {{bolig.areal}} m² - {{bolig.by}}
                <div class="float-right">
                  Oprettet: {{bolig.oprettelsesdato}}
                </div>
            </small>
        </div>
        <div class="bolig-husleje">
            {{bolig.husleje}},-
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and

```
$scope.roomsFilter = function (bolig) {
        var rooms = parseFloat(bolig.rooms);
        var number = parseFloat($scope.searchRooms);

        if (!rooms) {
            return false;
        }
        if (number === 5 && rooms < number) {
            return false;
        } else if (number && rooms !== number && number !== 5) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of ng-repeat you can use ng-for / ng-if

```
*ngFor="let bolig in boliger | filter: searchCity; let i=index;"
```

...then...

```
*ngIf="i < 5"
```